# MapView displays map in tilt instead of top up

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

Anyone know why the map is shown tilted instead of a top view? I am using arcgis js with WMS for the map. Inside the body you will need to put a div:

```
<div id="viewDiv"></div>
```

This is my js code:

```
var map, view, layer;

    require([
        "esri/tasks/Locator",
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/views/MapView",
        "esri/layers/WMSLayer"
    ], function (Locator, Map, MapView, WMSLayer) {
        layer = new WMSLayer({
            url: 'https://geoservices.informatievlaanderen.be/raadpleegdiensten/GRB-basiskaart/wms'
        });

        var locatorTask = new Locator({
            url:
                "https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer"
        });

        map = new Map({
            basemap: {
                baseLayers: [layer]
            }
        });

        view = new MapView({
            map: map,
            container: "viewDiv",
            constraints: {
                rotationEnabled: false
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean "tilted" vs "top down"? It's not possible for a 2d MapView to be any other perspective besides "top down".